# How to skip GitHub Actions job by labels

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

The following is one of my GitHub Actions yml files

```yaml
name: "Labeler"
on:
  issues:
    types: [ opened, edited, reopened ]

jobs:
  triage:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Label issues
    steps:
      - name: check out
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: labeler
        uses: jbinda/super-labeler-action@develop
        with:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
```

It can be seen from the code that this is a CI about the issue. My requirement is that when the issue has a label, the CI will not be executed or the job or step in the CI can be skipped.

Hope someone can answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To skip GitHub Actions execution workflow when it's been triggered on an issue already containing a label, you can use the [`if` syntax](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idif) to check the [`label` event context variable](https://docs.github.com/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#label):

```yaml
name: "Labeler"
on:
  issues:
    types: [ opened, edited, reopened ]
jobs:
  triage:
    # check if the issue has no label set 
    if: github.event.issue.labels.length == 0
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Label issues
    steps:
      - name: check out
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: labeler
        uses: jbinda/super-labeler-action@develop
        with:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
```

If you want to skip on a particular label only then use [`contains()` expression](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#contains) in the `if` statement:

```yaml
if: !contains(github.event.issue.labels.*.name, 'skip')
```

In this case the workflow will be skipped if the issue it was triggered is marked with `skip` label.

**Side note:**
I do not recommend this third-party [`jbinda/super-labeler-action`](https://github.com/jbinda/super-labeler-action)
action while we have an official [`super-labeler-action`](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/super-labeler) present in the GH marketpace.